# How to navigate to widgets outside of a Flutter Flame Engine game widget

Tags: flutter, dart, flame

Is it possible to navigate out of a Flame Engine game widget into other Flutter widgets?

The app below immediately loads the game widget. How can navigation outside of the Game widget to another Flutter widget be achieved?

Flutter version: 2.2.3
Dart version: 2.13.4
Flame Engine version: flame-1.0.0-rc8

**main.dart**

```
import 'package:flame/flame.dart';
import 'package:flame/game.dart';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:my_game.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(
    GameWidget(
      game: MyGame(),
    ),
  );
}
```

**my_game.dart**

```
import 'package:flame/extensions.dart';
import 'package:flame/game.dart';
import 'package:flame/gestures.dart';
import 'package:flutter/gestures.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class MyGame extends BaseGame with TapDetector {
    @override
    void update(double dt) { /* TODO */ }

    @override
    void render(Canvas canvas) { /* TODO */ }

    @override
    void onTapUp(TapUpDetails details) {
        // How to navigate outside of the game widget?
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't know this package but maybe if you create a normal page with a button that starts the game, then use the back button to get out of the game? So you change the runApp(Game) to a normal runApp(FirstPage()) thing and on this FirstPage you have the button that opens the game?

Comment: Yes that could work. But there may also be a state change within the game that would trigger a navigation. Just trying to understand how to to trigger a widget change from within the game widget.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do two things:

- Either put the `GameWidget` in a `Stack` and handle navigation by `Navigator` from Flutter and remove and add the `GameWidget` to the widget tree when deemed necessary. [Flutter Navigation docs](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/navigation)
- Use the `Overlays` API in Flame to handle the state from within Flame instead. [Flame docs](https://flame-engine.org/docs/#/game?id=flutter-widgets-and-game-instances)

For using the overlays you add the overlays that you want to have accessible when you create the `GameWidget` and then you call `game.overlays.add` to render a specific widget, and `game.overlays.remove` to stop rendering it.

I do recommend that you upgrade from `rc8` to `rc13`, since the docs are for that version and things are more stable in general.